# Content type Text field as Geolocation source field in View

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I have a text field(named as address) in my content type and I will store the address in that text field. Here I don't want to store the address in geolocation field so I have to use text field to store address.

I just created the View with page and have set Format as "Geolocation Google Maps API - CommonMap". In that Format settings I have to set Geolocation source field to display the Map. But I can't able to set Content type Text field as Geolocation source field.

Is there any way to set **Content type Text field as Geolocation source field**?

Answer (score 0):

Map formatters usually only take geolocation data in order to display them (latitude and longitude for example). There is a way to "convert" a textual address into geolocation data with the help of a Geocoding service.

So you *do* have to create a geolocation field. You can set it to automatically take the address and convert it to points on a map, and you can hide this field from users. It's a problem though if the address someone enters isn't correct in some way.

With the geodata ready in that field you can set your views map to use that field as the source for geo points on a map.

Here's a comparison of modules that can help you with this: [Comparison of Mapping modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1704948).

It seems your best bet is [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) Well Known Text and [Geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder).

Comment: So, Do I need to store the address in Geofield instead of Text field? Can you please explain in detail or let me know how to convert Text field address into Geolocation source field?

Comment: You need both fields, the usual text address for humans to enter information, and the other geofield that can be configured to automatically "read" the address and save the geo numbers, so users dont have to do anything except type the address. I'm not sure if you'll need to replace your text field with WKT field to make it work. WKT gives you suggestions as you type so it minimizes errors.

Comment: You can find configuration steps on Geocoder documentation page https://www.drupal.org/node/1355780

Comment: Actually users will not enters the address in that content type fields. The text address mapped with Salesforce field when cron run. Now I am getting the text address values. But getting the address in Text field in drupal instead of Geofield. So let me how to convert this to geofield source to display map in view.

Comment: Follow the steps from Geocoder doc to create a geofield with geocoder and configure it to use your text address as source. It should work if your Salesforce has correct addresses.

Comment: I just tried the same but when I save node after submitting the values then it shows HTTP 500 error. The node is not saving & also the value is not geocoding. Why?

Comment: Does the 500 error happen only after configuring the geocoder? Usually it's related to some other server configuration. It's difficult to know without more information. Can you include your configuration info in the question?

Comment: Its an Geocoder Error only. Here is the actual error : **Fatal error: Class 'Ivory\HttpAdapter\AbstractHttpAdapter' not found in /docroot/modules/contrib/geocoder/src/GeocoderHttpAdapter.php on line 12**

Comment: It seems to be a dependency issue. Have you used composer to install the module? Maybe you also need `egeloen/http-adapter`: [Ivory\\HttpAdapter\\AbstractHttpAdapter](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder/issues/2995941), [Package egeloen/http-adapter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-http/httplug instead](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder/issues/2772541).

Comment: Yes, I used composer to install the module. I referred that link as well but no luck.

Comment: Module installed after executing this `composer require drupal/geocoder` After that I added this in git by **git add modules/contrib/geocoder/, git add vendor/egeloen/, git add vendor/igorw/, git add vendor/willdurand/**. Finally I committed and push to the server. Is this right?

Comment: It seems that using the `composer require drupal/geocoder` is all you need to make it work (this is the usual way of installing modules in D8, it takes care of all the dependencies). Is this working now and no 500 server error? When it comes to versioning the modules and vendor folders aren't usually tracked, and it is just because that is all now managed with Composer, but if you don't use Composer on the server, then yes you need to copy/push all of those files up there so geocoder would work.

Comment: Still same error, I have installed the module using composer only. I am using acquia cloud & working in local after git clone

Comment: How can I directly install the module using composer directly on Acquia Cloud? Because I downloaded the module in local and then only I pushed it to server using Git

Comment: Acquia has documentation about this: https://docs.acquia.com/resource/composer/ you might also want to try contacting Acqui support and point them to that issue.